# Firefox lingering images on page reload

Tags: html, firefox, caching, web

I'm using Firefox 24.0. The problem (see title) does not seem to be a caching issue. The image actually reloads; however, the previous image is displayed until the new one is available. Which in my case, produces a page full of images that refresh at different times and it's hard to see what is new and what is old content. Neither IE nor Chrome have this problem, as the image is not shown until the new one is ready.

The only solutions that have occurred to me are to add a time-stamp or randon number to the image URL, or to hide the image using javascript until the image is loaded, then show it. However, **I would like a cleaner solution, on the server side if possible**, like specifying some header that would make Firefox forget the old image.

Here is the code showing the annoying effect. Variant 1 does not work well in Firefox:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddImage() {
        var imgElem = document.createElement('img');

        // Variant 1
        imgElem.setAttribute('src', 'http://localhost/ImageServer.asmx/GetImage');

        // Variant 2
        //imgElem.setAttribute('src', 'http://localhost/ImageServer.asmx/GetImage?r=' + Math.random());

        // Variant 3
        //imgElem.setAttribute('src', 'http://localhost/ImageServer.asmx/GetImage');
        //imgElem.style.display = 'none';
        //imgElem.setAttribute('onload', 'this.style.display = "block"');

        document.body.appendChild(imgElem);
    }
</script>
<body onload="AddImage()">
</body>
</html>
```

For completeness here is the server side code, which is an old fashion web service that alternates between two images and adds a delay to show the lingering effect.

```
static int imgNumber = 2;

[WebMethod]
public void GetImage()
{
     Thread.Sleep(2000); // Delay to see the effect of the lingering image

     HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0, s-maxage=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");

     imgNumber = imgNumber % 2 + 1;
     string strPathPrefix = @"A:\Path\";
     HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(strPathPrefix + imgNumber + ".png");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "variant 2" method, wherein you generate a unique URL by appending a randomly generated number to the end is completely valid and is a widely used method of preventing caching.

I would highly recommend going with this rather than trying to fix the problem with cache control headers as they can be unreliable. Some CDN's even ignore caching headers in attempt to save bandwidth and such.